# How can I write to statements in two lines?

Tags: python, interactive

I want to write the following code in the trinket interactive shell. I don't know how two write the second statement without having the first one evaluated when I press enter on my keyboard.

```
>>> 42 == 42
>>> 42 == 99
True
False
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by having the first statement be delayed?

Comment: Does `print(42 == 42); print(42 == 99);`  count?

Comment: Hi, I just want to write two statements and then get both statements evaluated at the same time. First: >>> 42 < 100 and then create a new line: >>> 42 > 100 and then press enter and having both statements evaluated. This give me the output True and False. I don't know how to type that in, so embarrassing...

Comment: This is such a basic question, I don't even know what keywords I should use to google it :-) hope, someone can give me an answer

Comment: okay, but WHY? What are you trying to do with it? I understand that you want the output "True" and "False" but what are you hoping to do with those outputs?

Comment: I just try to experiment. I am following the beginner course "automate the boring stuff with python" from Al Sweigart: https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter2/. You can see in the middle of the page that he has typed in this code. I don't know if the problem is that shell is in the browser. Anyway, if my question doesn't make sense for you - no problem. I just wondered, why Al Sweigart has typed the code like that or why it is displayed like that in the shell...does this happen with this type of interactive shell which is integrated in a website and loads every time when you open it?

Comment: Does `42 == 42; 42 == 99` all on one line do what you want? I'm not near a computer right now so can't really check.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Yes, that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a suite of statements on one line by separating them with a semicolon. The REPL will evaluate the entire suite before printing the output:

```
>>> 42 == 42; 42 == 99
True
False
```

Reference: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Ok, this works in the python shell. I think I have to get used to the trinket shell first, then I will understand how it differs from the python shell. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is not related to Python, it is all about how the `trinket` operates with the server.

After pressing "run code interactively", we can see the following requests:

[image]

First 3 of them are just preparing the environment. The fourth one contains the following body (started at 713.77 ms):

```
70:42["console",{"init":true,"files":"{}","input":"(4 < 5) and (5 < 6)"}]
```

And the fifth one is a websocket connection with the following frames (started at 858.40 ms):

[image]

As you can see, the code is sent in different requests (and even different protocols) and there is a chance (or maybe design choice) that the second code line is sent before the response for the first line has been received.

So, this particular case is not related to Python, it is all about how trinket communicates with the server.